# Проблема с функцией str+split

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идея в том,чтобы строку сделать массивом через функцию `str_split`, затем `array_sum` для сложения элементов.

получаю результат:

> Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in C:\php\catalog\zadanie1.php on line 16

Вопрос: почему `$sum` не воспринимается как массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что ты никуда не записываешь результат работы функций. Надо так

```
$number = 123456;
$array = str_split($number);
$sum = array_sum($array);
echo $sum;
```

Comment: спасибо.<?php
$number= 656451651465464;

$sum = 0;

function calculate($number){
$numberarray= str_split($number);
$arraysum = array_sum($numberarray);
echo $arraysum;
}
echo $number."<br>";
$sum = calculate($number);
?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = "123456";
$result = 0;
for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($number); $i < $j; $i++) {
    $result +=(int)$number[$i];
}
echo $result;
```